# Enhanced Ctrl + L and URL templates for comments, answers and questions

Tags: script, keyboard-shortcuts, markdown

- Shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> to add links to a comment.
- Define URL templates to make it easier to insert links to documentation.
- Shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> to remove a link in a comment (`[caret>|](link)` -> `caret>|`).
- Recognize certain phrases, and pre-fill the URL box (edit the `phraseToURL` method).

### Screenshot

[image: Insert Hyperlink Link Link Link]

Edit the source code of the script to configure it (edit this question to make selection easier).

---

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Stack Exchange enhanced Ctrl + L
// @namespace   Rob W
// @description Adds Ctrl + L to comments; URL templates
// @version     1.0.3
// @match       http://stackoverflow.com/*
// @match       http://meta.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match       http://superuser.com/*
// @match       http://meta.superuser.com/*
// @match       http://serverfault.com/*
// @match       http://meta.serverfault.com/*
// @match       http://askubuntu.com/*
// @match       http://meta.askubuntu.com/*
// @match       http://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @match       http://answers.onstartups.com/*
// @match       http://meta.answers.onstartups.com/*
// @match       http://stackapps.com/*
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

// (c) 2013 Rob W <gwnRob@gmail.com>
// Released to the public domain
// History:
// 30 May 2013 - Initial release: Ctrl + L for comments & URL templates.
//  9 Jun 2013 - Automatic recognition of patterns, Ctrl + L to undo link in comments, insert URL on press of Enter
// Part of the code (at the end, starting at "courtesyOfStackOverflow") were taken from dev.meta.stackoverflow.com

/*jshint browser:true*/
'use strict';

// Usage: http://docs.site.com/    (placeholder text surrounded by three spaces)   .html
var urls = [
    // Chrome extensions
    'https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/   (api name)   .html',
    'https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/   (api name)   .html#method-   (method name)   ',
    'https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/   (api name)   .html#event-   (event name)   ',

    // Firefox addon SDK
    'https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/   (eg sdk/page-mod)   .html',

    // MDN: CSS / JS
//    'https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/   (eg. document)   ',
//    'https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/   (eg. height or :hover)   ',
//    'https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/   (eg. Array/map)   ',

    // Web platform: HTML
//    'http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/html/elements/   ()   ',

    // jQuery
    'http://api.jquery.com/   ()   ',

    // Can I use?
    'http://caniuse.com/   (search or feat)   '
];

function formatURL(template_url, replacer) { // replacer = function(full_match, placeholder)
    return template_url.replace(/   \((.*?)\)   /g, replacer);
}
function phraseToURL(text) {
    text = text.replace(/^[\s`]+|[\s`]+$/g, '');// Trim space and backticks
    text = text.replace(/\s*\([\S\s]*?\)/, ''); // Trim parentheses and arguments
    var parts = text.split('.');
    var url = '';
    if (parts.shift() === 'chrome') {
        if (parts.length < 1) return; // chrome. ( nothing )
        var api = '';
        var suffix = '';
        if (parts[0] == 'experimental') { // chrome.experimental. (any API can be experimental)
            parts.shift();
            api += 'experimental.';
        }
        if (parts[0] == 'devtools') { // chrome.devtools
            parts.shift();
            api += 'devtools' + (parts.length ? '.' : '');
        } else if (parts[0] == 'input' || parts[0] == 'systemInfo') {
            api += parts.shift() + '.';
            if (!parts.length) return; // second part is required
        }
        if (parts.length) { // actual API name, if available
            api += parts.shift();
        }
        if (parts.length) {
            var name = parts.shift();
            if (/^on[A-Z]/.test(name)) {
                suffix = '#event-' + name;
            } else if (api == 'storage') {
                if (parts.length == 1) // chrome.storage.(sync/local)
                    suffix = '#property-' + name;
                else if (/^[A-Z]/.test(parts[0])) // chrome.storage.(sync/local).CONSTANT
                    suffix = '#property-' + name + '-' + parts[0];
                else // chrome.storage.(sync/local).method
                    suffix = '#method-StorageArea-' + parts[0];
            } else if (parts.length === 0 && !/^(lastError$|id$|inIncognitoContext$)/.test(name)) {
                // Not chrome.(runtime/extension).lastError
                //     chrome.runtime.id
                //     chrome.extension.inIncognitoContext
                suffix = '#method-' + name;
            } else {
                suffix = '#property-' + name + (parts.length ? '-' + parts.join('-') : '');
            }
        }
        if (api) {
            return 'https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/' + api + '.html' + suffix;
        }
    }

}
var cssTemplate = (function() {/*
.ctrl-l-box {
    // Your preferences:

    max-height: 400px;
    top: 200px;
    // WMD box has a width of 400px
    width: 800px;
    margin-left: -200px;
    padding: 10px;

    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    text-align: left;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
.ctrl-l-link-row a {
    float: right;
}
.ctrl-l-param {
    width: 6em;
    padding: 0 3px;
    height: 1.2em;
}
*/}).toString()
    .replace(/^[\S\s]*?\/\*\s+/, '') // Strip  function() { /*
    .replace(/\s*\*\/\s*\}\s*$/, '') // Strip  */ }
    .replace(/^\s*\/\/.*/gm, ''); // Strip "comments"

// Add Ctrl + L functionality
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode != 76 /* L */ || !event.ctrlKey || event.altKey || event.shiftKey || event.metaKey)
        return; // Not (just) Ctrl + L
    if (event.target.nodeName.toUpperCase() != 'TEXTAREA')
        return; // Not an input field
    if (event.target.id.indexOf('wmd-input') === 0) { // starts with wmd-input
        handleWMDInput(event.target);
        return;
    }
    // At this point, assume a comment
    handleComment(event.target);
    event.preventDefault();
}, false);

var _commentDisabledTimestamp = 0; // Avoid submission of comment after setting link
function temporaryDisableCommentSubmission() { _commentDisabledTimestamp = 300 + Date.now(); }
document.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode != 13)
        return; // Not Enter
    if (event.target.name !== 'comment' || event.target.nodeName.toUpperCase() != 'TEXTAREA')
        return; // Not a comment field
    if (Date.now() < _commentDisabledTimestamp) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
}, true);

function handleWMDInput(wmdInput) {
    var selectedValue = wmdInput.value.substring(wmdInput.selectionStart, wmdInput.selectionEnd);
    setTimeout(handleWMDInput_, 0, selectedValue);
}
function handleWMDInput_(selectedValue) {
    var wmddialog = document.querySelector('.wmd-prompt-dialog');
    var urlbox = wmddialog.querySelector('form input[type="text"]');

    var setURL = function(url) {
        urlbox.value = url;
    };
    var extraBox = createExtraBox(setURL);
    onEnterPressOk(extraBox, wmddialog, setURL);
    wmddialog.appendChild(extraBox);

    // Reposition the container
    var marginTop = parseFloat(wmddialog.style.marginTop);
    wmddialog.style.marginTop = (marginTop - extraBox.offsetHeight/2) + 'px';

    // Auto-suggestion for common formats
    var suggestedURL = phraseToURL(selectedValue);
    if (suggestedURL) setURL(suggestedURL);
}
function onEnterPressOk(extraBox, wmddialog, setURL) {
    extraBox.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13 && /\bctrl-l-param\b/.test(event.target.className)) {
            var url = elemToURL(event.target);
            if (url) {
                setURL(url);
                // Click OK
                wmddialog.querySelector('input[type="button"][value="OK"]').click();
            }
        }
    }, false);
}
function handleComment(textarea) {
    var value = textarea.value;
    var selectedValue, existingLink;
    var selectionStart = textarea.selectionStart;
    var selectionEnd = textarea.selectionEnd;

    var extractLink = function() {
        selectedValue = value.substring(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
        existingLink = /^(\s*)\[(.*?)\]\(.*?\)(\s*)$/.exec(selectedValue);
    };
    extractLink();
    if (!existingLink) {
        if (value.charAt(selectionStart - 1) == '[' && value.substr(selectionEnd, 2) == '](') {
            selectionStart -= 1;
            selectionEnd = value.indexOf(')', selectionEnd) + 1; // Assume no parentheses in URL
            if (selectionEnd > 0) extractLink();
        }
    }

    if (existingLink) {
        textarea.value = value.substring(0, selectionStart) +
                         existingLink[1] + existingLink[2] + existingLink[3] +
                         value.substring(selectionEnd);
        textarea.selectionStart = selectionStart + existingLink[1].length;
        textarea.selectionEnd = textarea.selectionStart + existingLink[2].length;
    } else {
        courtesyOfStackOverflow(textarea, temporaryDisableCommentSubmission);
        handleWMDInput(textarea);
    }
}

function createExtraBox(setURL) {
    var extraBox = document.createElement('div');
    extraBox.className = 'ctrl-l-box';
    extraBox.innerHTML = createBoxContents();
    var choose = function(event) {
        var url = elemToURL(event.target);
        if (url) setURL(url);
    };
    extraBox.addEventListener('click', choose, false);
    extraBox.addEventListener('input', choose, false);
    addStyleIfNeeded();
    return extraBox;
}
function createBoxContents() {

    // Uses global `urls` = array of strings

    var escapeHTML = function(s) {
        return s.replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
                .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
                .replace(/>/g, '&gt;')
                .replace(/"/g, '&quot;')
                .replace(/'/g, '&#39;');
    };
    return urls.map(function(url) {
        var url_escaped = escapeHTML(url);
        var html = '<div class="ctrl-l-link-row" data-url="' + url_escaped + '">';
        html += '<span>';
        html += formatURL(url_escaped, function(full_match, placeholder) {
            // Placeholder is already a HTML-escaped string
            return '<input type="text" placeholder="' + placeholder + '" title="' + placeholder + '" class="ctrl-l-param">';
        });
        html += '</span>';
        html += '<a href="' + url_escaped + '">Link</a>';
        html += '</div>';
        return html;
    }).join('\n');
}
function elemToURL(elem) {
    while ( elem && !elem.classList.contains('ctrl-l-link-row') )
        elem = elem.parentNode;
    if (!elem || !elem.classList.contains('ctrl-l-link-row'))
        return;
    var template_url = elem.dataset.url;

    var fields = elem.querySelectorAll('.ctrl-l-param');
    var i = 0;
    var url = formatURL(template_url, function() {
        return fields[i++].value;
    });
    elem.querySelector('a[href]').href = url;
    return url;
}

function addStyleIfNeeded() {
    if (!cssTemplate) return;
    var style = document.createElement('style');
    style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cssTemplate));
    document.head.appendChild(style);
    cssTemplate = null; // Insert just once
}


var courtesyOfStackOverflow;
(function() {
    // Wrapper to use SO's code:
    courtesyOfStackOverflow = function(textField, postProcessing) {
        var selectionStart = textField.selectionStart;
        var selectionEnd = textField.selectionEnd;
        var value = textField.value;
        var selectedText = value.substring(selectionStart, selectionEnd) || defaultsStrings.linkdescription;

        var linkDefaultText = 'http://';

        var linkEnteredCallback = function(link) {
            background.parentNode.removeChild(background);

            if (link) {
                var newStuff = '[' + selectedText + '](' + properlyEncoded(link) + ')';
                textField.value = value.substring(0, selectionStart) + newStuff + value.slice(selectionEnd);
                textField.selectionStart = selectionStart + 1; // 1 = '['
                textField.selectionEnd = selectionStart + 1 + selectedText.length;
            } else {
                textField.selectionStart = selectionStart;
                textField.selectionEnd = selectionEnd;
            }
            textField.focus();
            postProcessing();
        };

        var background = ui.createBackground();
        ui.prompt(defaultsStrings.linkdialog, linkDefaultText, linkEnteredCallback);
    };

    // Courtesy of Stack Overflow, http://dev.meta.stackoverflow.com/content/js/wmd.js
    var ui = {};
    var position = {};
    var util = {};
    var defaultsStrings = {
            link: "Hyperlink <a> Ctrl+L",
            linkdescription: "enter link description here",
            linkdialog: "<p><b>Insert Hyperlink</b></p><p>http://example.com/ \"optional title\"</p>",
    };

    var doc = document;
    position.getTop = function (elem, isInner) {
        var result = elem.offsetTop;
        if (!isInner) {
            while ( (elem = elem.offsetParent) ) {
                result += elem.offsetTop;
            }
        }
        return result;
    };

    position.getHeight = function (elem) {
        return elem.offsetHeight || elem.scrollHeight;
    };

    position.getWidth = function (elem) {
        return elem.offsetWidth || elem.scrollWidth;
    };

    position.getPageSize = function () {
        var self = window;

        var scrollWidth, scrollHeight;
        var innerWidth, innerHeight;

        // It's not very clear which blocks work with which browsers.
        if (self.innerHeight && self.scrollMaxY) {
            scrollWidth = doc.body.scrollWidth;
            scrollHeight = self.innerHeight + self.scrollMaxY;
        }
        else if (doc.body.scrollHeight > doc.body.offsetHeight) {
            scrollWidth = doc.body.scrollWidth;
            scrollHeight = doc.body.scrollHeight;
        }
        else {
            scrollWidth = doc.body.offsetWidth;
            scrollHeight = doc.body.offsetHeight;
        }

        if (self.innerHeight) {
            // Non-IE browser
            innerWidth = self.innerWidth;
            innerHeight = self.innerHeight;
        }
        else if (doc.documentElement && doc.documentElement.clientHeight) {
            // Some versions of IE (IE 6 w/ a DOCTYPE declaration)
            innerWidth = doc.documentElement.clientWidth;
            innerHeight = doc.documentElement.clientHeight;
        }
        else if (doc.body) {
            // Other versions of IE
            innerWidth = doc.body.clientWidth;
            innerHeight = doc.body.clientHeight;
        }

        var maxWidth = Math.max(scrollWidth, innerWidth);
        var maxHeight = Math.max(scrollHeight, innerHeight);
        return [maxWidth, maxHeight, innerWidth, innerHeight];
    };

    util.addEvent = function(elem, event, listener) { elem.addEventListener(event, listener, false); };
    util.removeEvent = function(elem, event, listener) { elem.removeEventListener(event, listener, false); };

    ui.createBackground = function () {

        var background = doc.createElement("div"),
            style = background.style;

        background.className = "wmd-prompt-background";

        style.position = "absolute";
        style.top = "0";

        style.zIndex = "1000";

        style.opacity = "0.5";

        var pageSize = position.getPageSize();
        style.height = pageSize[1] + "px";

        style.left = "0";
        style.width = "100%";

        doc.body.appendChild(background);
        return background;
    };

    ui.prompt = function (text, defaultInputText, callback) {

        // These variables need to be declared at this level since they are used
        // in multiple functions.
        var dialog;         // The dialog box.
        var input;         // The text box where you enter the hyperlink.


        if (defaultInputText === undefined) {
            defaultInputText = "";
        }

        // Used as a keydown event handler. Esc dismisses the prompt.
        // Key code 27 is ESC.
        var checkEscape = function (key) {
            var code = (key.charCode || key.keyCode);
            if (code === 27) {
                close(true);
            }
        };

        // Dismisses the hyperlink input box.
        // isCancel is true if we don't care about the input text.
        // isCancel is false if we are going to keep the text.
        var close = function (isCancel) {
            util.removeEvent(doc.body, "keydown", checkEscape);
            var text = input.value;

            if (isCancel) {
                text = null;
            }
            else {
                // Fixes common pasting errors.
                text = text.replace(/^http:\/\/(https?|ftp):\/\//, '$1://');
                if (!/^(?:https?|ftp):\/\//.test(text))
                    text = 'http://' + text;
            }

            dialog.parentNode.removeChild(dialog);

            callback(text);
            return false;
        };



        // Create the text input box form/window.
        var createDialog = function () {

            // The main dialog box.
            dialog = doc.createElement("div");
            dialog.className = "wmd-prompt-dialog";
            dialog.style.padding = "10px;";
            dialog.style.position = "fixed";
            dialog.style.width = "400px";
            dialog.style.zIndex = "1001";

            // The dialog text.
            var question = doc.createElement("div");
            question.innerHTML = text;
            question.style.padding = "5px";
            dialog.appendChild(question);

            // The web form container for the text box and buttons.
            var form = doc.createElement("form"),
                style = form.style;
            form.onsubmit = function () { return close(false); };
            style.padding = "0";
            style.margin = "0";
            style.cssFloat = "left";
            style.width = "100%";
            style.textAlign = "center";
            style.position = "relative";
            dialog.appendChild(form);

            // The input text box
            input = doc.createElement("input");
            input.type = "text";
            input.value = defaultInputText;
            style = input.style;
            style.display = "block";
            style.width = "80%";
            style.marginLeft = style.marginRight = "auto";
            form.appendChild(input);

            // The ok button
            var okButton = doc.createElement("input");
            okButton.type = "button";
            okButton.onclick = function () { return close(false); };
            okButton.value = "OK";
            style = okButton.style;
            style.margin = "10px";
            style.display = "inline";
            style.width = "7em";


            // The cancel button
            var cancelButton = doc.createElement("input");
            cancelButton.type = "button";
            cancelButton.onclick = function () { return close(true); };
            cancelButton.value = "Cancel";
            style = cancelButton.style;
            style.margin = "10px";
            style.display = "inline";
            style.width = "7em";

            form.appendChild(okButton);
            form.appendChild(cancelButton);

            util.addEvent(doc.body, "keydown", checkEscape);
            dialog.style.top = "50%";
            dialog.style.left = "50%";
            dialog.style.display = "block";
            doc.body.appendChild(dialog);

            // This has to be done AFTER adding the dialog to the form if you
            // want it to be centered.
            dialog.style.marginTop = -(position.getHeight(dialog) / 2) + "px";
            dialog.style.marginLeft = -(position.getWidth(dialog) / 2) + "px";

        };

        // Why is this in a zero-length timeout?
        // Is it working around a browser bug?
        setTimeout(function () {

            createDialog();

            var defTextLen = defaultInputText.length;
            if (input.selectionStart !== undefined) {
                input.selectionStart = 0;
                input.selectionEnd = defTextLen;
            }
            else if (input.createTextRange) {
                var range = input.createTextRange();
                range.collapse(false);
                range.moveStart("character", -defTextLen);
                range.moveEnd("character", defTextLen);
                range.select();
            }

            input.focus();
        }, 0);
    };

    // takes the line as entered into the add link/as image dialog and makes
    // sure the URL and the optinal title are "nice".
    function properlyEncoded(linkdef) {
        return linkdef.replace(/^\s*(.*?)(?:\s+"(.+)")?\s*$/, function (wholematch, link, title) {
            link = link.replace(/\?.*$/, function (querypart) {
                return querypart.replace(/\+/g, " "); // in the query string, a plus and a space are identical
            });
            link = decodeURIComponent(link); // unencode first, to prevent double encoding
            link = encodeURI(link).replace(/'/g, '%27').replace(/\(/g, '%28').replace(/\)/g, '%29');
            link = link.replace(/\?.*$/, function (querypart) {
                return querypart.replace(/\+/g, "%2b"); // since we replaced plus with spaces in the query part, all pluses that now appear where originally encoded
            });
            if (title) {
                title = title.trim ? title.trim() : title.replace(/^\s*/, "").replace(/\s*$/, "");
                title = title.replace(/"/g, "quot;").replace(/\(/g, "&#40;").replace(/\)/g, "&#41;").replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
            }
            return title ? link + ' "' + title + '"' : link;
        });
    }
})(); // End of closure for wmd.js code
```

Comment: Feel free to share your URL templates in an answer.